# How to make use of i++ operator in a set statement in c#

Tags: c#

Is there a special method that you can add if you get an i++ type of operation on a property?

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do. I know this don't work, but this gives you an idea of what I'm talking about. Actually, I'm working with two internals and I want to increase one on + and the other on -.

```
int mynum;
int yournum 
{
    get{ return mynum; }
    set{ mynum = value; }
    set++{ mynum = mynum + 5; return mynum; } //this is what I want to do
}
// elsewhere in the program
yournum++; //increases by 5
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?  I don't understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you want to override the behavior which occurs when `++` is invoked on the property `yournum`.  If so that's not possible in C# for exactly the code you outlined in your sample.  The `++` operator should be incrementing by `1` and every user calling `yournum++` would expect that behavior.  To change it silently to `5` would certainly lead to user confusion

It would be possible to get similar behavior by defining a type with a custom `++` operator which did the `+ 5` conversion instead of `+1`.  For example

```
public struct StrangeInt
{
    int m_value;

    public StrangeInt(int value)
    {
        m_value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator StrangeInt(int i)
    {
        return new StrangeInt(i);
    }

    public static implicit operator int(StrangeInt si)
    {
        return si.m_value;
    }

    public static StrangeInt operator++(StrangeInt si)
    {
        return si.m_value + 5;
    }
}
```

If you now defined `yourname` to be `StrangeInt` then you would get the behavior you were looking for

Comment: How do I overload the get for the struct (so I can work on the return value)? This is actually part of my problem I'm working on, though I was in a hurry when I wrote the example and didn't have time to include everything. Also, do the operators have to be static? Or is there a reason for doing so?

Comment: @ArlenBeiler I'm not quite sure what you mean by "overload the get".  If you're trying to overload how the property `get` works on a given type that's not possible.  As for the operators yes they have to be static.  As to why that's just how C# defines them.  Likely an issue of consistency.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Here is my final code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11367723/258482 And it does make sense to make the operators static. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes but (always a but)... the property type can't be `int`, you would need to return a custom proxy type which implicitly converts to int but overrides operators.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do this directly. One way to provide this (if you really need it), would be to provide your own type instead of `int` and use [operator overloading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to implement the functionality you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to override the `++` operator for integers then that won't unfortunately be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Create your own struct and overload the operator:

```
    public static YourType operator++(YourType t)
    {
            // increment some properties of t here
            return t;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to JaredPar for [his excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11366656/258482). Here is the end result if anyone is interested. It is to calculate a percentage based on two numbers in order to add weight (hence the name) as more numbers come in.

```
public struct Weight
{
    int posWeight;
    int negWeight;
    int Weight
    {
        get
        {
            if (posWeight + negWeight == 0) //prevent div by 0
                return 0;
            else return posWeight / (posWeight + negWeight);
        }
    }
    public static Weight operator ++(Weight num)
    {
        num.posWeight++;
        if (num.posWeight > 2000000) //prevent integer overflow
        {
            num.posWeight = num.posWeight / 2;
            num.negWeight = num.negWeight / 2;
        }
        return num;
    }
    public static Weight operator --(Weight num)
    {
        num.negWeight++;
        if (num.negWeight > 2000000) //prevent integer overflow
        {
            num.posWeight = num.posWeight / 2;
            num.negWeight = num.negWeight / 2;
        }
        return num;
    }
    public static explicit operator int(Weight num) 
    { // I'll make this explicit to prevent any problems.
        return num.Weight;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not possible using a primitive type. What I would do instead is add an extension method to int -- something like:

```
public static int plusFive(this int myInt)
{
    return myInt + 5;
}
```

then, to use it, you can just do something like:

```
int a,b;
a = 5;
b = a.plusFive();
```